# Developing and testing Kubernetes API extensions

Tags: intellij-idea, go, kubernetes

I want to run/build Kubernetes from source. I normally use Intelij idea to open sources but I can't see that there is a source support for 'Go' in my ide. My main concern is to write an extension for Kubernetes API. How can I easily setup source in idea to develop and test that extension? I also have a locally installed Kubernetes API.

Answer (score 1):

Install Golang plugin for IDEA:
https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/wiki/Documentation